# Git fast undo all changed with one command

Tags: bash, git, awk, grep, git-bash

We have a **big** repo... and drive encryption. So `git reset --(whatever)` takes quite long. Let's imagine a situation:

- you're on a feature branch
- you have some configuration changed
- you want to `checkout master a-clean && pull`
- checking out master is not possible straight away because you have made some changes

There are several options I know to revert those changes:

1. `git reset --hard` --> slow
2. `git checkout .` in root dir --> seems it's identical to reset --hard, and slow as well the same way
3. `git stash` - takes even longer
4. `git status` and then `git checkout -- (filename)`. Now, that's fast, but you have to repeat it for every file!

Myself and *bash* don't understand each other very well, so doing something fancy like `git status | grep modified: | awk "git checkout -- {%2}"` is something beyond my current knowledge.

However, maybe there's a command in mgit that does git checkout -- to all the "modified:" files?

Comment: Does a hard reset of one commit really take so long?  Anyway, there is another possibility, which is that you want to keep the work in your current directory (and maybe stage as well).  In this case, `git stash` comes in handy.

Comment: Thanks @TimBiegeleisen I know stash and it takes even longer. I'll update the question with it.

Comment: maybe something like `git status -s | grep -Po '^ ?M ?\K.*' | xargs git checkout -- `

Comment: I don't think that running `git checkout` multiple times is going to be any faster than `git reset --hard`.  You're going to end up doing the same thing in both cases.

Comment: @larsks i don't think either, however xargs limits number of calls by putting as much arguments a shell command can contain, and from the question `git checkout .` whas slow

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul, this seems to work for me. If you put this as an answer, I'll accept it.
For those who are interested this command (I aliased it `qreset`) runs about 2 seconds for 5 files, while `checkout .` takes more than a minute... and crashes Visual Studio :(

Comment: Oh FFS, and how did you expect me to ask this question so it's not downvoted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git status -s | grep -Po '^ ?M ?\K.*' | xargs git checkout --
```

- `-s` short format useful to parse
- `grep -Po` : `-P` perl regex `\K` keep out of match left of `\K`,  `-o` print matches
- `xargs` repeat argument as much shell command can accept

Comment: For those who will use this response, you can alias this using your `.bashrc` file in the location you get after `cd ~`. Aliases explained here: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/aliases.html Don't forget to restart git bash after it. `alias qreset="git status -s | grep -Po '^ ?M ?\K.*' | xargs git checkout -- "`